# What does :/= mean in %date:/=%?

Tags: variables, batch-file

While searching for a way to create a date-named directory in Windows, I came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5485853/520162) with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485929/520162) accepted answer.

There's a comment below the accepted answer:

> To make it more easy: `mkdir %date:/=%`

So, `%date%` prints the current date, but what does `:/=` do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means substitute for the string between the <kbd>:</kbd> and the <kbd>=</kbd> with the string after the <kbd>=</kbd> and before the closing <kbd>%</kbd>

So it strips out any <kbd>/</kbd> from the variable `%date%` which is set by default to the current date.

Comment: Read your profile and wanted to reach out to you personally besides IT and computing. Have a story to share you might like. Can I contact you somehow?

Comment: you can del it now. Thank you. You will hear from me in the next couple of hours. Thank you very much for getting back to me.

Answer (score 9):

The form of the command is

```
%variable:text=replace%
```

and it removes `text` and inserts `replace` in the same spot.

In your case the `replace` is empty so it just removes any `/` characters from the date string.